# parse text file delimited by | operator and retain the header column name

Tags: java, spring, parsing, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have an text file in which the fields are separated by | operator. First line in the txt file holds the column Names. I am able to parse and split the fields based on | operator using Scanner but i need the header column name for each field value

Please find my sample text file content which needs to be parsed below:
FirstName||lastName||Age||Salary

Kong||King||20||$1000

Steve||Rogers|| ||$2000

Mark||Richer||30||$12000

Spencer||Cook||31||$700

---

Result which i get now:

FirstName

lastName

Age

Salary

Kong

King

20

$1000

Steve

Rogers

$2000

Mark

Richer

30

$12000

Spencer

Cook

31

$700

---

sample code which i used:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\sample\\sample.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    scanner.useDelimiter("[\\||]");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scanner.next().trim());

    }
    scanner.close();
    }
```

Result which i need is like below:

FirstName -> Kong

lastName -> King

Age -> 20

Salary -> $1000

---

FirstName -> Steve

lastName -> Rogers

Age ->

Salary -> $2000

Any Help is appreciated..

Comment: Just use any standard CSV library and stop reinventing the wheel.  Any parser will do this correctly in a couple of lines of code. I would suggest that you create a bean type for your objects - then read into a list of beans. [For example](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_beans).

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if it is the most efficient solution but managed it like this, hope it helps! :) The file path is different because I am in Linux.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/dzandes/Music/test.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
scanner.useDelimiter("[\\||]");

List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {

     String s = scanner.next().trim();

     // First, we split the Strings with new line in between
     if (!s.isEmpty()) {
          if (s.contains("\n")) {
              String[] s_ = s.split("\n");
              for (String str : s_) {
                   contents.add(str);
               }
           } else {
               contents.add(s);
           }       
      } else {
           contents.add(s);
      }
 }
 scanner.close();

 // Then we keep the necessary empty Strings we need, e.g. Steve Roger's age, and skip the rest
 List<String> contents_ = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int j = 0; j < contents.size(); j++) {
      if (!contents.get(j).isEmpty()) {
           contents_.add(contents.get(j));
      } else {
           if (contents.get(j+1).isEmpty() 
                  && contents.get(j-1).isEmpty()) {
               contents_.add(contents.get(j));
            }
       }
  }

  /**
   * Just left this for-loop to see what the list contains after the above
   * 
   * Of course, you can comment it
   */
   for (String s : contents_) {
       System.out.println("s :" + s);
   }

   int i = 1;
   while (i*4 < contents_.size()) {
        System.out.println(contents_.get(0) + " - " + contents_.get(i*4));
        System.out.println(contents_.get(1) + " - " + contents_.get((i*4) + 1));
        System.out.println(contents_.get(2) + " - " + contents_.get((i*4) + 2));
        System.out.println(contents_.get(3) + " - " + contents_.get((i*4) + 3));
        i++;
    }
```

It prints,

```
FirstName - Kong
lastName - King
Age - 20
Salary - $1000
FirstName - Steve
lastName - Rogers
Age - 
Salary - $2000
FirstName - Mark
lastName - Richer
Age - 30
Salary - $12000
FirstName - Spencer
lastName - Cook
Age - 31
Salary - $700
```

Comment: "_The file path is different because I am in Linux._" - Java is platform agnostic; your OS has no bearing on path syntax.

Comment: Just mentioned it so that it doesn't look strange to our friend when he checks the response. I tried to help on my way with a solution that works, even if it is not the most efficient one (a fact that I mention). We are here to help each other and learn, I guess... If you believe this effort deserves a down vote, then, congrats, you are the cool guy of the day!

Comment: Hint: you can write much better code than this by just using two scanners. I didn't downvote because of the path, I downvoted for 2 reasons - 1) this is basically a code only answer, there is absolutely no explanation of what you are doing or how it works - as you point out this is a teaching site, 2) the code is messy and hard to understand, with strange workarounds because of using a single scanner -  if you're going to post an answer, make sure it's clean and correct.

Comment: Scanner was used by the guy that asked, that is why I kept it as is. The rest are simply some fors and ifs with relevant comments, not any strange workaround that is hard to understand. Even if it was strange, he could ask it himself and I would be glad to give further explanations. What you did was a "read this" solution, anyone could do that. Anyway, I am not gonna keep on this anymore, I respect your opinion even though totally disagreeing on your way of thinking.